# Detect connection issues in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

this questions is related to an html file calling out different pages in different iframe tags.  Is there a way, using JavaScript probably, to check if there was a connection issue to the page? If so, to try reloading this frame until the connection is established.

To be a bit clearer, if you have a look at the following link (http://tvgl.barzalou.com) (even if the content is in French, you will notice how different parts of the page load, and more often than not, loads correctly).  But once in a while, during the weekend, a slight connection issue to the net arrives and for some reason, the frame gives out this ridiculous grey / light grey icon saying that there was a connection issue.  Of course, when the page is manually reloaded, the frame comes back to life.

Comment: Could put loading masks over them and hide each mask by using iframe load event. Set a timer to show a refresh button inside mask after a time you deem appropriate and cancel timer when iframe loads also

Comment: never use iframes for the design... it's very bad for searchengines

Comment: I respect your comment Chris but in my case, I don't worry about search engines for the purpose of this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a code which will check whether the iframes are loaded properly or not

Consider a sample

```
<script language="javascript">
     var attempts = 0;
     var maxattempt = 10;
     var intid=0;
     $(function()
     {
         intid = setInterval(function() 
         {
            
            $("iframe").each(function()
            {
               if(iframeHasContent($(this))) 
               {
                  //iframe has been successfully loaded
               }
               
               if(attempts < maxattempt)
               {
                 attempts++;
               }
               else
               {
                 clearInterval(intid);
               }
            })
         },1000);
     })

     function iframeHasContent($iframe)
     { 
         if($iframe.contents().find("html body").children() > 0)
         {
            return true; 
         }

         return false;
     }   
</script>
```

This simple code snippet will check whether iframes in the document have been loaded properly or not. It will try this for 10 attempts then it will abort the checking.

When the checking is aborted, you can call iframeHasContent() for each iframe to shortlist the ones that have not been loaded and reload them if required.

Comment: I am very impressed by the thought you've put into this answer.  If I understand it correctly, it does not actually attempt to reload the iframe (s) that has no content, but just checks the status?  In my case, I am trying to have it reload the frame as soon as the error event is triggered and the function stops executing when all the iframes are loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for appreciating my answer, I have mentioned in my answer that you can shortlist the iframe that have not been loaded, and load them again. The code will need a simple update to check the iframes and reload them using src attribute of the iframe. If you want i can post a separate answer describing my update of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated code that will check and reload the iframe after the max attempts have been reached...

```
<script language="javascript">
 var attempts = 0;
 var maxattempt = 10;
 var intid=0;
 $(function()
 {
     intid = setInterval(function() 
     {

        $("iframe").each(function()
        {
           if(iframeHasContent($(this))) 
           {
              //iframe has been successfully loaded
           }

           if(attempts < maxattempt)
           {
             attempts++;
           }
           else
           {
             clearInterval(intid);
             checkAndReloadIFrames();

           }
        })
     },1000);
 })

 function iframeHasContent($iframe)
 { 
     if($iframe.contents().find("html body").children() > 0)
     {
        return true; 
     }

     return false;
 }   
 
 function checkAndReloadIFrames()
 {
     $("iframe").each(function()
        {
            //If the iframe is not loaded, reload the iframe by reapplying the current src attribute
           if(!iframeHasContent($(this))) 
           {
               //reload iframes if not loaded 
               var $iframe = $(this);
               var src = $iframe.attr("src");
               //code to prevent cache request and reload url
               src += "?_" + new Date().getTime();

               $iframe.attr("src",src);
           }
        });
 }
 </script>
```